# .attr.replace() not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason I can't get my code to work

```
var mainImg = $("#LayoutDiv1").children("img").attr("src").replace("myFull", "mytinythumbs");
```

It draws from this and it isn't a problem with the setup as other functions work just fine, for some reason it doesn't replace myFull instead it just leaves it there.

```
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
        <a href="#" id="btn-back"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="btn-forward"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        <img id="pusher" class="resize" src="../images/myFull/Young_Diego.jpg" alt="page1">

    </div>
```

EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::

The code suddenly decided to work...not sure what the error was before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var mainImg = $("#LayoutDiv1").children("img").attr("src").replace("myFull", "mytinythumbs");
```

add this at below

```
$("#LayoutDiv1").children("img").attr("src",mainImg);
```

Comment: No, I don't need to replace the html code with the new string. I need to use the string later on in my js code to find a different img link. the problem is the value isn't changing with .replace

Comment: have you use    console.log(mainImg)   or  console.log($("#LayoutDiv1").children("img").attr("src")) to see  can get the src or not ?

Comment: I used an alert function that fired when I clicked on the image. However it seems to suddenly be working for some reason when it wasn't before.